# Unable to delete .db file from within my script, but can do so from anywhere else

Tags: python, sqlite

If I run the below script, it throws the error shown. However, if I switch the the terminal and run the same command to delete the file (`os.remove("test.db")`), the file is removed.

```
import gc
import os
import time

from sqlite3 import connect
from contextlib import contextmanager


file = "test.db"


@contextmanager
def temptable(cur: object):
    cur.execute("create table points(x, int, y int)")
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        cur.execute("drop table points")


with connect(file) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    with temptable(cur=cur):
        cur.execute("insert into points (x, y) values(1, 1)")
        cur.execute("insert into points (x, y) values(1, 2)")
        cur.execute("insert into points (x, y) values(2, 1)")
        for row in cur.execute("select x, y from points"):
            print(row)
        for row in cur.execute("select sum(x * y) from points"):
            print(row)

os.remove(file)
```

> > > File "c:\Users\You_A\Desktop\2019Coding\context_generator_decorator.py", line 32, in 
> > >           os.remove(file)
> > >       PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'test.db'

Again, running `os.remove("test.db")` in any terminal successfully removes the file.

Comment: You are already using the file in the process

Comment: Where in the process you have mentioned the use of `os.remove("test.db")`?

Comment: I don't know your intent but if it's about using SQLite3 temporarily without saving any results to a file, you could use `:memory:` instead of filename.  Also, why `DROP TABLE` if the whole file is to be deleted?  Also, a single `INSERT` is enough: `cur.execute("insert into points (x, y) values(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 1)")`

Comment: @tonypdmtr Just attempting to figure out context managers, decorators and generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be caused due to the connection to the database not being closed. Try using `contextlib.closing()`. The modified code would look like,

```
import gc
import os
import time

from sqlite3 import connect
from contextlib import contextmanager, closing


file = "test.db"


@contextmanager
def temptable(cur: object):
    cur.execute("create table points(x, int, y int)")
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        cur.execute("drop table points")


with closing(connect(file)) as conn:
    # cur = closing(conn.cursor()) --> if auto-closing of cursor is desired
    cur = conn.cursor() # if auto closing of cursor is not desired
    with temptable(cur=cur):
        cur.execute("insert into points (x, y) values(1, 1)")
        cur.execute("insert into points (x, y) values(1, 2)")
        cur.execute("insert into points (x, y) values(2, 1)")
        for row in cur.execute("select x, y from points"):
            print(row)
        for row in cur.execute("select sum(x * y) from points"):
            print(row)

os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Can you change cur = closing(conn.cursor()) --> cur = conn.cursor() so I can accept it as the answer? Code is good without that.

Comment: The issue with the former statement is: AttributeError: 'closing' object has no attribute 'execute'